# R set value in dependency of another value

Tags: r, dataframe

For each row of my dataframe, I want to calculate a value from numbers taken from columns of this dataframe. If the calculated value is above 2, I want to set another columns value to 0, else to 1.

```
x=(df$firstnumber+df$secondnumer)/2
if(x>2){
df$binaryValue=0}
else{ df$binaryValue=1}
```

this throws the error

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

because x is a vector

How can I solve this? One way would be to write this as a function and to apply it to the dataframe - are there any other options?

Also, how could I write this to work with appl() ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
transform(df, BinaryValue = as.numeric(firstnumber + secondnumber > 4))
```

There's no need to divide by two in the first place. You could check whether the sum is greater than four. The function `as.numeric` is employed to transform boolean to numeric (0 and 1) values.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply do...

```
df$BinaryValue <- ifelse( x > 2 , 0 , 1 )
```

So you get...

```
df <- data.frame( x = 1:5 , y = -2:2 )
x <- df$x + df$y
df$BinaryValue <- ifelse( x > 2 , 0 , 1 )

df
#     x  y BinaryValue
#   1 1 -2           1
#   2 2 -1           1
#   3 3  0           0
#   4 4  1           0
#   5 5  2           0
```

Comment: It can be simplified to `df$BinaryValue <- ifelse(df$x + df$y > 2, 0, 1)`.

Comment: @musically_ut yes you are right. I was just following the OPs use of the `x` vector, but you are right, I should have looked to improve upon it rather than just try to answer the question